# can me subdivide a selected faces from loaded model

Tags: javascript, selected

I created this code to load an existed model and subdivide a selected faces.

```
var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
var geometry = event.content;           
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:0xFFFFFF , specular: 0x0, shading: THREE.FlatShading, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );                   
geometry.dynamic=true;
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++ ) 
    {
        face = geometry.faces[ i ]; 
        face.color.setRGB( 0, 0, 0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2 );       
    }
    var faceColorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
    { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,faceColorMaterial );
                    mesh.position.set( 0, - 0.5, 0 );
                mesh.rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 2, 0 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 5, 5, 5 );
                    scene.add( mesh );              targetList.push(mesh);
    projector = new THREE.Projector();
                } );
        loader.load('http://localhost/tessellation/data/Mesh20.ply');
```

the selected faces is choosed are selected by the user clicking on faces.

The objective of this work is to refine a mesh portion by the subdivision of its faces.

To do it we created this code :

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
{
    console.log("Click.");
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {

var smooth = THREE.GeometryUtils.clone( intersects[0].object.geometry );

var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(1);

modifier.modify( smooth );

intersects[0].object.geometry = smooth;

}
```

but the totality of the mesh is subdivided not the selected faces.
can you help me to subdivide selected part of loaded model.

[the program subdivide the totality of mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaG5c.png)

Comment: "can me subdivide a selected faces from loaded model" what?

Comment: a part model chosen by the client. The client select the faces that wants to refine (to subdivise)

Comment: Can you provide some minimal set of faces that are subdivided incorrectly?

Comment: the program subdivide the totality of the mesh

Comment: see the figure ; the program subdivide the totality of mesh